# How can I install GCC on Mac OS X Lion without Xcode?

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I find it really hard to believe there is not a simple solution to install GCC on Mac without having to download and install more than 1 GB+ of [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). I found a site that helps reduce the amount of programs to be installed in the Xcode installation, but it's still a relatively large amount of disk space needed just to get this compiler up and running.

I'm looking for a solution WITHOUT Xcode.

Comment: So your only issue is the size of the download?

Comment: yes, I have several Mac computers that I only need *nix related tools on.  I don't develop with xcode, and don't care for it's tools / ide. I understand that the issue is with program dependencies, but until a second ago, I wasn't able to find any solutions.

Comment: I've used [macports.org](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gcc) in the past.

Comment: Doesn't mac ports rely on xcode also?

Comment: Loki, I don't think you get it.  The whole point of the question is to install it without xcode. I don't like it.  The thought of it taking up drive space irritates me.

Comment: @EricLeroy I am not 100% sure that macports works without some xcode these days, hence I haven't posted an answer. It worked wwithout xcode with older versions of Mac OSX.

Comment: yeah, it requires xcode:  http://www.macports.org/install.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### [OSX GCC Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)
>
> Downloading and installing the massive Xcode installer is a huge hassle if you just want GCC and related tools.
>
> The osx-gcc-installer allows you to install the essential compilers from either pre-built binary packages or helps you create your own installer.

Comment: Since then superseded by Apple's official Command Line Tools for Xcode:
http://kennethreitz.org/experiments/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew

Answer (score 0):

You can install just the Xcode Command Line Tools, which includes a GCC Compiler, through Terminal. All you have to do is enter `gcc` into the Terminal and it should prompt you to install; only took a few minutes for me the other day.

Check out this tutorial for the full instructions: http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

[Install macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing) and then [gcc9](https://ports.macports.org/port/gcc9/) Brew may fail because it needs the compiler in advance.